# Images being squished in safari mobile

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

Forgive my if my html and css is bad this is my first page im doing alone. I have been working on this issue for atleast 3 hours I have my index page complete looks halfway decent but when I commit it to github and view it on my sons iphone the images look squished and the aspect ratio is off. If I can have any help thanks in advance!!

html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
    <title>RealtorsRUs</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Begin Navbar -->
    <header class="hero">
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
        <h1 class="logo">
          <a href="index.html">MReality</a>
        </h1>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a class="current" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <!-- End Navbar -->
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Welcome Home</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque vero
          excepturi dolore sequi quibusdam nostrum aperiam voluptatum nihil
          deserunt explicabo!
        </p>
        <a href="about.html" class="btn">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <!-- Begin Featured Listings -->
      <section class="featuredlistings">
        <h2>Featured Listings</h2>
        <div class="flex-row">
          <div class="item1">
            <img
              src="images/evelyn-paris-XJnP4L958ds-unsplash.jpg"
              alt="Home"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="item2">
            <img
              src="images/jesse-roberts-561igiTyvSk-unsplash.jpg"
              alt="Home"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="item3">
            <img
              src="images/daniel-barnes-RKdLlTyjm5g-unsplash.jpg"
              alt="Home"
            />
        </div>
      </section>

      <article id="section-1" class="flex-row-article">
        <div class="article-1">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore mollitia, ipsa neque aliquid quod similique consequatur accusantium harum facere natus. Omnis blanditiis incidunt nobis similique reprehenderit illo quaerat, sed ad reiciendis fugit sequi molestias, inventore, exercitationem consectetur soluta. Quibusdam quod laborum eaque, perferendis fugit similique dolorem ipsum mollitia sunt incidunt?
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="article-2">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam ut dignissimos vitae voluptatum, obcaecati quidem, eaque, amet cum illo eos numquam iste officiis quia aspernatur animi dicta consectetur nulla eligendi! Laboriosam quas sunt dolor dignissimos illo at porro asperiores, earum, cum sapiente voluptates nemo animi dolore repellat libero cupiditate nulla?
          </p>
        </div>
      </article>
    </main>
    <footer id="mainfooter">
      <p>MReality &copy; 2020, All Rights Reserved</p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
enter code here
```

css

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  font-size: 20px;
  opacity: .95;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
 
}

.flex-row div{
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;

}
.flex-row h3{
  font-size: 3rem;  
}
.flex-row-article {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
body {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  z-index: 2;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  border-bottom: #fff 2px solid;
}
.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.logo{
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.hero-aboutus {
  background: url("../images/roger-starnes-sr-BNY7m7BhS2o-unsplash.jpg") no-repeat center
    center/cover;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.hero-contactus {
  background: url("../images/bailey-anselme-Bkp3gLygyeA-unsplash\ \(2\).jpg")
    no-repeat center center/cover;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  background-position-y: 40%;
}

.hero {
  background: url("../images/francesca-tosolini-XAHSexPxSus-unsplash\ \(1\).jpg")
    no-repeat center center/cover;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hero .content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.hero .content h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.hero .content p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 30px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.hero:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.featuredlistings h2{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.article-1 p, .article-2 p{
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  width: 50%;

}

#mainfooter p{
  text-align: center;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 100;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .navbar a {
    padding: 10px 10px;
    margin: 0 3px;
  }

  .flex-row{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .featuredlistings h2{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  .article-1 p, .article-2 p{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    width: 100%;
  }
  img{
   flex: 1;
  }
  .flex-row .item1 .item2 .item3{
```

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome at SO! Which images? You use 6: 3 as background and 3 as element. Are they all messed up on a mobile? Futhermore, the CSS @media you posted is not complete (rather essential with a mobile problem) and your HTML has a missing closing `</div>` (probably closing `<div class="flex-row">`). Also, your images a not accessible here, so please make them reachable or state some sizes we can fill in for 'placeholder.com' (or some site like that).

Comment: Thank you @RenevanderLende I was missing the div I forgot about the validator and fixed it. I dont know if posting links is allowed but here is the full site https://amolina0116.github.io/MyProjects/realtorsite to check out the photos. Only the 3 in featured get squeezed and stretched vertical in safari. The first one is the worst the other 2 are not as noticeable

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be fairly easy to solve. May be, as I am not on Safari, but IE11 seems to have the same problem.

Solution

- `img: { max-width: 100% }` should be `img: { width: 100% }`. Because element width and height are CSS default `auto`, which means that the browser will try to fill all the space available with the image, fully disregarding its ratio (it stretches in every direction). `width: 100%` (OR `height: 100%`, not both!) will make sure that images fill the full width (OR height) of the available space and size its height (OR width) to ratio.
- `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { .... img { flex: 1 } .... }` should become `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { .... img { flex-grow: 1 } .... }`. Especially IE11 cannot handle the shorthand property `flex` very well, so you need the individual properties instead [CSS flex Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp). I am not sure, but Safari may have the same problem (may need the vendor prefix -webkit-).

Before, IE11 did not show the images at all with a browser window smaller than 768px and did not preserve the image ratios when resizing, but with my changes everything works as expected. Hopefully, Safari too!

**BTW** Chrome, Edge and Firefox did not show the problem on W10.

**The snippet** (code copied from your Github site) with the two changes.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  font-size: 20px;
  opacity: 0.95;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-row div {
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-row h3 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.flex-row-article {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  z-index: 2;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  border-bottom: #fff 2px solid;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.navbar h1 {}

img {
  /*  max-width: 100%;/* REMOVED */
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.hero-aboutus {
  background: url("https://amolina0116.github.io/MyProjects/realtorsite/images/roger-starnes-sr-BNY7m7BhS2o-unsplash.jpg") no-repeat center center/cover;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.hero-contactus {
  background: url("https://amolina0116.github.io/MyProjects/realtorsite/images/bailey-anselme-Bkp3gLygyeA-unsplash\ \(2\).jpg") no-repeat center center/cover;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  background-position-y: 40%;
}

.hero {
  background: url("https://amolina0116.github.io/MyProjects/realtorsite/images/francesca-tosolini-XAHSexPxSus-unsplash\ \(1\).jpg") no-repeat center center/cover;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hero .content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.hero .content h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.hero .content p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 30px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.hero:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.featuredlistings h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.article-1 p,
.article-2 p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  width: 50%;
}

#mainfooter {
  height: 50px;
  background: #333;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  width: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#mainfooter p {}

.ourteam {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.fred {
  background: #333;
  opacity: 0.9;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  /*  height: ; /**/
}

.fred img {
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.sammy {
  background: #333;
  opacity: 0.9;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.sammy img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box1 {
  border-right: black solid 1px;
  width: 33.3%;
}

.box2 {
  width: 33.3%;
}

.box3 {
  border-left: black solid 1px;
  width: 33.3%;
}

input[type="text"],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 30%;
  opacity: 0.85;
  margin: 0 30%;
}

.contactform {
  height: 60vh;
}

#subject {
  height: 100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #icons {
    display: none;
  }
  .contactform {
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 0.5;
  }
  .container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 80px;
  }
  .fred {
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
  }
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 100;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .flex-row {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .featuredlistings h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  .article-1 p,
  .article-2 p {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    width: 100%;
  }
  img {
    flex-grow: 1;
    /* MODDED, was flex: 1 */
  }
  .fred img {
    height: 80px;
  }
}

.sammy img {}
```

```html
<!-- Begin Navbar -->
<header class="hero">
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
    <h1 class="logo">
      <a href="index.html">MReality</a>
    </h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="current" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="contact.html">Contact </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- End Navbar -->
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Welcome Home</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque vero excepturi dolore sequi quibusdam nostrum aperiam voluptatum nihil deserunt explicabo!
    </p>
    <a href="about.html" class="btn">Read More</a>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <!-- Begin Featured Listings -->
  <section class="featuredlistings">
    <h2>Featured Listings</h2>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="item1">
        <img src="https://amolina0116.github.io/MyProjects/realtorsite/images/evelyn-paris-XJnP4L958ds-unsplash.jpg" alt="Home" />
      </div>
      <div class="item2">
        <img src="https://amolina0116.github.io/MyProjects/realtorsite/images/jesse-roberts-561igiTyvSk-unsplash.jpg" alt="Home" />
      </div>
      <div class="item3">
        <img src="https://amolina0116.github.io/MyProjects/realtorsite/images/daniel-barnes-RKdLlTyjm5g-unsplash.jpg" alt="Home" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <article id="section-1" class="flex-row-article">
    <div class="article-1">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore mollitia, ipsa neque aliquid quod similique consequatur accusantium harum facere natus. Omnis blanditiis incidunt nobis similique reprehenderit illo quaerat, sed ad reiciendis fugit sequi
        molestias, inventore, exercitationem consectetur soluta. Quibusdam quod laborum eaque, perferendis fugit similique dolorem ipsum mollitia sunt incidunt?
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="article-2">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam ut dignissimos vitae voluptatum, obcaecati quidem, eaque, amet cum illo eos numquam iste officiis quia aspernatur animi dicta consectetur nulla eligendi! Laboriosam quas sunt dolor dignissimos
        illo at porro asperiores, earum, cum sapiente voluptates nemo animi dolore repellat libero cupiditate nulla?
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>
</main>
<footer id="mainfooter">
  <p>MReality &copy; 2020, All Rights Reserved</p>
</footer>
```